# rich:popupPanel remove the border from the popup

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have the following popupPanel in my JSF Page.

```
<rich:popupPanel id="popup" modal="true" autosized="true"
            resizeable="false" domElementAttachment="form">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Process Teller Transaction" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="controls">
                <h:outputLink value="#"
                    onclick="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide(); return false;">
                x
             </h:outputLink>
            </f:facet>

            <h:panelGroup id="container" layout="block">
                <div id="container">

                    <!--Popup Content -->



                </div>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </rich:popupPanel>
```

Now if i remove the header facet, from the popup the header disappears. What i want is to have a custom header panel, that is more intune with my application. How can i do this. Secondly the popup should be drag gable. Is there anyway i can achieve this  ?

Kind Regards,

Comment: If you remove header facet it should disappear from the panel for sure . What exactly do u want to do to the header?

Comment: what version of richfaces are u using?

Comment: I am using Rich Faces 4. Removing the header facet, the header does disappear, but the popup is not drag able anymore.

Comment: if you check richfaces demo it is draggable, may be there's some mistake you are doing. try this out first http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=popup&skin=blueSky